# Filtering rows in a table using checkboxes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a table which is used to display data from a table in a database. I want to be able to filter the rows of the table, by selecting specific shops from a list of checkboxes. If the check box is ticked the the data for that shop will be displayed in the table.

This is the table that I am trying to filter: It is the BettingShop column which will be compared to the checkboxes in order to filter the rows

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @string.Format("{0:ddd dd MMM yyyy}", item.DailyReportDate)

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Estate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BettingShop)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCashStake)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberCashSlips)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShopBalance)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCashIn)
            </td>
            <td class="alignRight">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalCashOut)
            </td>
       </tr>
    }
```

Comment: you need to do via jquery or via ajax, are all reordsa are loaded in table at once?

Comment: Yeah all of the records are loaded at once

Comment: then you need filtering on jquery side